# Disable start menu from opening with keyboard combo?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I prevent the start menu from opening by using the keyboard shortcuts / combo (aka windows key and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>) ?

I am able to hide the taskbar, and receive the keys but I don't know how do I disable them, I need to disable it until the user is authenticated with the system.

Is there a policy I can use to disable them or how do I do it ?

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?  A typical Windows login will not load the taskbar (or the desktop, or any chrome) until the user is authenticated.

Comment: @harpo I am working on an application to control a lanhouse and after windows has logged in the application kicks in with the fullscreen authentication window.

Comment: You worry about the wrong keys.  Ctrl+Alt+Del is next.  Windows already has great authentication support, rock solid and time tested after being exposed to millions of hack attempts.  Use it.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Del` is already taken care off by disabling the task manager in the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for hooks

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

**Update**:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A *global hook* monitors messages for
>   all threads in the same desktop as the
>   calling thread. A *thread-specific hook*
>   monitors messages for only an
>   individual thread. A global hook
>   procedure can be called in the context
>   of any application in the same desktop
>   as the calling thread, so the
>   procedure must be in a separate DLL
>   module. A thread-specific hook
>   procedure is called only in the
>   context of the associated thread.

In other words, if you use a global hook like in the link, you can capture system events and either process them like normal events or suppress them.

**Another Update**: Here is another [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx) which was created with the Windows key and CTRL+ESC in mind.

Comment: That does not disable the function of opening the start menu but thx, that is pretty much what I have when I mentioned i can receive the keys.

Comment: How exactly are you capturing the keys?  Are you doing it locally or globally?

Answer (score -1):

Would the example here be what you are looking for?
http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx

Comment: Link is dead, please fix

Answer (score -1):

I've never done this myself, but I heard that you should replace explorer shell with your program for that kind of application. Look into it, maybe it's the way to go..

http://www.ehow.com/how_5688935_replace-window-shells.html

https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.server.scripting/browse_frm/thread/fa1760ad06c77259?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: This doesn't work