# Is it possible to trap the Windows Start Menu popup via Windows key(possibly without a hook)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events, message

I've been working on an input event system.
I mapped all the keys on my own keyboard, the scancodes and so on, including both windows keys.
When I press them, the program successfully receives the distinct keydown events for them without any trouble.
When I release the keys, however, the Start Menu pops up, obscuring the program in windows mode, or even minimizing it in fullscreen.

So my problem lies in suppressing that.

Arma 2, a Military Simulator/Game allows commands to be mapped on those keys without any trouble.

Where do I have to catch that event? 
Can I do it for my own window as long as it has focus?
Am I going to be stuck with a disabled win-key as long as it is running?
Or something else?

Googling it was mainly fruitless due to Windows key also referring to the product key, and when I did find something, it usually flat out disabled the whole button.
I just want to suppress the popup.

Edit:
I tried

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        switch(wParam)
        {

        case SC_TASKLIST:
            return 0;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

But that gave me very odd results.
If I spammed the winkeys and only the winkeys, it seemed to work, as soon as I moved the mouse while doing so, it didn't, the start menu would pop up again.

Edit:
I also tried hooks, but on win7 they get removed if the callback takes too much time, which can happen when large data is loaded, so they suggest a dedicated thread for it, but I think that's overkill for just one key that needs handled.

I just want to know where the Start Menu gets called. My own program? The system?
This is so friggin annoying, I am contemplating trying to reach the people from Bohemia Interactive and ask them how they did it.

Just this one key, sheesh Microsoft...even with "Super key/superkey" search terms, I usually only get flat out disabling methods, from registry changes to third party background programs.

Bah!

Comment: Another name for the windows key is the superkey.  it might give you different results in google

Comment: I'm going to hate your game. How will I get back to my desktop?

Comment: @David: control-alt-delete would still work - I hope. :-)

Comment: @David: the system hot-keys are unaffected by this, alt-tab and the like still work. I'd go crazy myself if that weren't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raw Input API should solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543.aspx

Comment: Funny, I did use RawInput, but your post made me check the docs, again. Do you by any chance refer to the "RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS" flag that can be used when registering a device? Cause that seems to fix it, just wanna be sure here

Comment: It would have been preferable if you had mentioned that you were already using RawInput - but in this case I guess it worked out for the best.  I wasn't specifically aware of RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS, but it certainly sounds as if you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

[This artcile was relating to C# but may point you in the right direction;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586168/disable-start-menu-from-opening-with-keyboard-combo)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A global hook monitors messages for all threads in the same desktop as
>   the calling thread. A thread-specific hook monitors messages for only
>   an individual thread. A global hook procedure can be called in the
>   context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread,
>   so the procedure must be in a separate DLL module. A thread-specific
>   hook procedure is called only in the context of the associated thread.

[This was the most helpful link in order to answer the question in the above article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx)